# Removing the LivePreview and Share Buttons?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, live-preview

Is there a way to deactivate this functionality? We dont want our clients to use it just yet.

I could delete them with my Module's js, but it is triggered after the site is build and the "popping" away of the buttons is not really pretty.

Comment: There are several ways to deactivate them... first of all you can include custom CSS that hides those so they won't pop up, furthermore you can extend the JS classes in order to remove their functionality and remove them.

Comment: Well, hiding the buttons with css really was the easiest way of them all. I tried to make it more complicated than necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a blank or invalid template path in your Section's settings (Settings > Sections > Edit Section) then both live preview and the share button will be disabled.